# p5.js for loop used for mouse collission detection outputs overlaying text tags

Tags: collision-detection, p5.js

[Overlaying text tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBC6d.png)

I'm trying to display the text of my numerous bubbles while hovering the mouse over them, but when multiple bubbles overlay, so does the displayed text. I'm trying to figure out a way of "detecting" when I have more than 1 text command displaying information, so I can arrange and order them in the screen without them colliding. Bellow is a little code I've made based on my actual project that illustrates the issue. I've tried sending all the detected indexes into an array but the result is a never ending array... I hope my explenation is clear. I'm relatively new to coding and pretty lost at the moment. Any direction or ideas would be much appreciated!

```js
let bubbles = {
  pos: [],
  diam: [],
  color: [],
  id: []
}

let initialR = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);

  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    bubbles.pos.push(createVector(random(0, width), random(0, height)));

    bubbles.color.push(color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), 120));

    bubbles.diam.push(random(0, 80));

    bubbles.id.push(round(random(0, 1000)));

  }
  console.log(bubbles)
}

function draw() {
  background(10);

  mX = mouseX;
  mY = mouseY;

  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

    initialR += 0.01;
    consR = constrain(initialR, 0, bubbles.diam[i]);

    stroke(0);
    fill(bubbles.color[i]);
    ellipse(bubbles.pos[i].x, bubbles.pos[i].y, consR);


    dBubbles = dist(mX, mY, bubbles.pos[i].x, bubbles.pos[i].y);

    if (dBubbles < bubbles.diam[i] / 2) {

      textX = bubbles.pos[i].x;
      textY = bubbles.pos[i].y;

      textSize(20);
      fill(255);
      text(bubbles.id[i], textX, textY);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because you didn't share the code that was resulting in a "a never ending array" it is hard to identify specifically what you are struggling with. Identifying the fact that you have multiple labels showing, and that some of them overlap, is fairly trivial. Displacing them so they don't overlap is more difficult. I've made an attempt in the answer below.

Comment: Your approach is much more efficient than my beginner mistake. I kept pushing all the values detected by the if statement to an array and the array got updated each frame, resulting in a thousands long array with many repeated values. After seeing your code bellow, I don't think it's worth revisiting that part of my code. Thank you very much, you answer provides much needed insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```js
let bubbles = {
  pos: [],
  diam: [],
  color: [],
  id: []
}

let initialR = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    bubbles.pos.push(createVector(random(0, width), random(0, height)));

    bubbles.color.push(color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), 120));

    bubbles.diam.push(random(0, 80));

    bubbles.id.push(round(random(0, 1000)));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(10);

  let mX = mouseX;
  let mY = mouseY;
  
  // Use a local variable to tack the hovered bubbles for each frame
  let hovered = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    initialR += 0.01;
    consR = constrain(initialR, 0, bubbles.diam[i]);

    stroke(0);
    fill(bubbles.color[i]);
    ellipse(bubbles.pos[i].x, bubbles.pos[i].y, consR);

    dBubbles = dist(mX, mY, bubbles.pos[i].x, bubbles.pos[i].y);

    if (dBubbles < bubbles.diam[i] / 2) {
      // Don't draw the labels yet, just add the bubble index to the hovered list.
      hovered.push(i);
    }
  }

  textSize(20);
  fill(255);

  // Find the center of the hovered spheres
  let center =
    hovered.map(ix => bubbles.pos[ix])
    // This reduce function computes an running average of all the
    // hovered bubble centers. It is basically using a weighted
    // average formula (avgₙ = (avgₙ₋₁ * count + valueₙ) / (count + 1))
    // with the terms rearranged to prevent a loss of precision for very large lists.
    .reduce(
      (acc, pos) => ({
        center:
          acc.center.mult(acc.count / (acc.count + 1))
             .add(p5.Vector.mult(pos, 1 / (acc.count + 1))),
        count: acc.count + 1
      }), {
        center: createVector(0, 0),
        count: 0
      }
    ).center;

  // Find the width and displacement direction for each label
  let labels = hovered.map(ix => ({
    pos: bubbles.pos[ix].copy(),
    width: textWidth(bubbles.id[ix]),
    text: bubbles.id[ix],
    offsetDirection: p5.Vector.sub(bubbles.pos[ix], center).normalize()
  }));

  // There are probably better ways to displace the labels so that they don't overlap
  for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    // offset the current label until it doesn't collide with any other labels
    while (true) {
      let overlapping = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
        if (i !== j) {
          if (abs(labels[j].pos.x - labels[i].pos.x) < (labels[j].width + labels[i].width) / 2 &&
            abs(labels[j].pos.y - labels[i].pos.y) < 20) {

            overlapping = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      if (overlapping) {
        // At the very least we could jump by exactly the required offset to prevent
        // the currently detected overlap, but this just increases the offset
        // by ~1 pixel at a time
        labels[i].pos.add(labels[i].offsetDirection);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  for (const lbl of labels) {
    text(lbl.text, lbl.pos.x, lbl.pos.y);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for this! it's exactly what I needed. But I must admit some of your code goes beyond the scope of my understanding and I'm currently viewing the MDN Web docs, will have to study it  to understand exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Free_Parallel I added a few more comments. Let me know if there is anything specific you have questions about. I'm guessing my use of reduce is the most confusing thing. Here's a good article about the reduce function: https://thecodebarbarian.com/javascript-reduce-in-5-examples.html